# Upgrading Rails 3 app from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 stops respecting latin1 encoding specification in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, ruby-1.9, mysql2, latin1

I'm upgrading a Rails 3.2.13 application from Ruby 1.8.7-p370 to Ruby 1.9.3-p385. After upgrading, special characters are garbled in text retrieved from the database. For instance "café" appears as "cafÃ©". My database is latin1 encoded. I'm using mysql2 (0.3.11) and my `database.yml` looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: latin1
  database: my_db
  username: root
  host: localhost
```

(The same problem is also happening in the production environment, which has the same database config.)

It appears that when ActiveRecord retrieves text from the database, it decodes it as if it were utf-8, not latin1 (or ISO-8859-1) as I've specified.

To diagnose the problem, I wrote a Ruby script that that uses mysql2 to query the database directly, bypassing ActiveRecord:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost",
                            :username => "root",
                            :database => "food52_development_production",
                            :encoding => "latin1")

result = client.query('SELECT title FROM recipes WHERE id = 12934')

puts result.first["title"]
```

The recipe with id 12934 has the word "café" in its title. Running this script in 1.9.3 outputs the correctly decoded text ("café"). If I change the `:encoding` option to `"utf-8"`, I once again see the garbled text ("cafÃ©").

I also tried placing a breakpoint in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters`, to see how what encoding configuration Rails was initializing the `Mysql2::Client` with. It is being passed `:encoding => "latin1"`, as expected.

And yet: somewhere along the line, Rails decides to decode the text as utf-8. How do I get Rails to respect the latin1 encoding configuration I specified? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What are your system specs?

Comment: @tylerdavis, I'm running OS X 10.8.2, but the same problem occurs in production, which is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.9.3, iconv is deprecated.  Also, Rails 3 expects UTF-8 encoding on all input.

With that said, you've got a couple different options.  The first, is pretty hacky, but if you don't want to migrate your data, it will work.

The iconv library is still available as a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/iconv), which you should be able to use to manually to do those conversions whenever necessary in your app.

The guys over at Airbnb use a helper like this:

```
def self.convert_string_encoding(to, from, str)
  if "1.9".respond_to?(:force_encoding)
    str = str.dup if str.frozen?
    str.encode(to, from, :undef => :replace)
  else
    require 'iconv'
    Iconv.conv(to, from, str)
  end
end
```

to handle the conversions.  You could potentially throw this in a helper for your views.

You can read more about their migration [here](http://nerds.airbnb.com/upgrading-from-ree-187-to-ruby-193)

The problem will be when trying to convert rails' default UTF-8 back to your databases' encoding.

What would probably make more sense is to do a migration to UTF-8 on your existing data.

[This article seems to cover that fairly well.](http://climbtothestars.org/archives/2004/07/18/converting-mysql-database-contents-to-utf-8/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: So, `some_string.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8')` does the conversion just fine: https://gist.github.com/hoffm/5207153

However, I'm not sure how to use this information to fix my app.

Comment: There're patches online that you can try for your database, or you can do a one time script to re-encode all of the fields in your database to UTF-8.  One of the issues is, Rails expects UTF-8 as default, so the data re-encode script might be your best bet moving forward.  

[Here's an article on how to convert your database.](http://climbtothestars.org/archives/2004/07/18/converting-mysql-database-contents-to-utf-8/)

Another [another article](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/17/encodings-unabridged/) on the differences in 1.9 and Rails 3.

Comment: Thanks, Tyler. I plan to do the conversion eventually, but I was hoping not to have to do it simultaneously with the 1.9 migration.